# webflux security multi roles in same match

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux

I use spring security in spring cloud gateway. cloud version is Finchely.SR2 and spring boot version is 2.0.x

Then i set two role in one matcher like this:

```
            .pathMatchers("/apis/**").hasRole("TEST1")
            .pathMatchers("/apis/**").hasRole("TEST2")
```

but, when i startup application and do test, just TEST1 role can access. TEST2 role get FORBIDDEN 403 response.

I know in spring-boot-starter-web with spring-security, it has any method like

```
             .antMatchers("/apis/**").hasAnyRole("TEST1", "TEST2")
```

Does webflux spring security has any API like hasAnyRole(String...roles) to use?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one available in the base APIs from Spring Security, however I've been using the following for `anyAuthority`,

```
public class HasAnyAuthority<T> implements ReactiveAuthorizationManager<T> {

    private final Collection<String> allowedAuthorities;

    public HasAnyAuthority(Collection<String> allowedAuthorities) {
        this.allowedAuthorities = allowedAuthorities;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<AuthorizationDecision> check(final Mono<Authentication> authentication,
            T object) {
        return authentication.filter(Authentication::isAuthenticated)
                .flatMapIterable(Authentication::getAuthorities)
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).any(allowedAuthorities::contains)
                .map(AuthorizationDecision::new)
                .defaultIfEmpty(new AuthorizationDecision(false));
    }
```

with usage like,

`.access(new HasAnyAuthority<>(allowedAuth.getAuthorities())`

Answer (score 0):

`hasAnyRole` and `hasAnyAuthority` will be available in WebFlux in Spring Security 5.2.0.
You can try them out now in 5.2.0.M3.
The syntax is the same

```
.pathMatchers("/apis/**").hasAnyRole("TEST1", "TEST2")
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone

```
.pathMatchers("/apis/**")
            .access((mono, context) -> mono.map(auth -> auth.getAuthorities().stream()
                .filter(e -> (e.getAuthority().contains(TEST1) || e.getAuthority().contains(TEST2)))
                .count() > 0)
                .map(AuthorizationDecision::new))
```